# How to compute a large weighted matrix in R efficently?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix

I have a large (sparse) matrix named *assay_name* with **m** columns and **n** rows. I have a second large (sparse) matrix *term* with **n** columns and **p** rows. I want to compute a matrix *assay_term* with **m** columns and **p** rows.

For each column **m** (eg. m<sub>1</sub>) in *assay_name* I look wether there is a nonzero element of **n** (e.g. n<sub>1</sub>) and then muliply that value `assay_name[n1,m1]` with the row of the corresponding column (n<sub>1</sub>) of *term* `term[,n1]`. This gives me a weightend row of *term*. Afterwards I calculate the rowsum of all the weighted rows form *term* and this gets to be the corresponding row of *assay_term*.

These are the dimension of the two sparse matrices:

```
assay_name
22620 x 21574 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix", with 74651618 entries
term
22712 x 22620 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix", with 1898915 entries
```

The basic approach for one column m<sub>1</sub> takes long already:

```
system.time(a<-sapply(row.name(assay_name)[which(assay_name[,1] != 0)], function(y) {   
      as.numeric(assay_name[y,1])*term[,y]
  }))

380.9
```

So just just performing

```
assay_term<-sapply(colnames(assay_name),function(x){
  rowSums(do.call(cbind,(row.name(assay_name)[which(assay_name[,x] != 0)], function(y) {   
      as.numeric(assay_name[y,x])*term[,y]
  }))))
}
```

will take at least 21574*380.9s = 95.1d, which is not feasable.

With the help of ChatGPT I have come to the following solution:

```
# Set up parallel backend
library(doParallel)
ncores <- detectCores()
registerDoParallel(ncores)

# Define function to be applied in parallel

assay_term <- foreach(x = colnames(assay_name), .combine = cbind) %dopar% {
  rowSums(do.call(cbind,sapply(row.name(assay_name)[which(assay_name[,x] != 0)], function(y) {   
      as.numeric(assay_name[y,x])*term[,y]
  }))))
}

# Clean up parallel backend
stopCluster(cl)
```

This starts computing, but it crashes after ~10 min by exceding the RAM limit (120 GB). Do you have any idea how to perform the calcuation more efficient or store the intermediate products?

Comment: Can you post a **small** reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a matrix multiplication of the transpose of the two matrices. The following should take about a minute for the dimensions given by the OP if the matrices are arranged so that `rownames(assay_name) == colnames(term)`.

```
assay_term <- t(crossprod(assay_name, t(term)))
```

The following demonstrates this with dummy data, starting with smaller matrices.

Dummy data:

```
library(Matrix)

m <- 2262L
n <- 2157L
p <- 2271L
x <- 74652L
y <- 1899L

assay_name <- sparseMatrix(
  i = c(sample(m, x - 1L, 1), m),
  j = c(sample(n, x - 1L, 1), n),
  x = runif(x)
)

term <- sparseMatrix(
  i = c(sample(p, y - 1L, 1), p),
  j = c(sample(m, y - 1L, 1), m),
  x = runif(y)
)
```

First, time the `crossprod` approach.

```
system.time(assay_term <- t(crossprod(assay_name, t(term))))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0
```

Next, time the `sapply` approach.

```
system.time(
  assay_term2 <- as(
    sapply(
      1:ncol(assay_name),
      function(x) {
        rowSums(
          do.call(
            cbind,
            lapply(
              which(assay_name[,x] != 0),
              function(y) as.numeric(assay_name[y,x])*term[,y]
            )
          )
        )
      }
    ), "sparseMatrix"
  )
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   19.48    0.27   19.78
```

Check that both approaches give the same result.

```
all.equal(assay_term, assay_term2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Now with the full sized matrices:

```
m <- 22620
n <- 21574
p <- 22712
x <- 74651618
y <- 1898915

assay_name <- sparseMatrix(
  i = c(((idx <- (sample(m*n - 2, x - 1L) - 1)) %% m) + 1, m),
  j = c((idx %/% m) + 1, n),
  x = runif(x)
)

term <- sparseMatrix(
  i = c(((idx <- (sample(p*m - 2, y - 1L) - 1)) %% p) + 1, p),
  j = c((idx %/% p) + 1, m),
  x = runif(y)
)

system.time(assay_term <- t(crossprod(assay_name, t(term))))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   63.50    4.58   68.08
```

Comment: Thank you! This is truely the best approach. I used `tic()
assay_term <- as(apply(assay_name, 2, function(x){
  weighted_term <- term[,x != 0]
  rowSums(t(t(weighted_term) *x[x != 0] ))
}), "sparseMatrix")
toc()
1336.436 sec elapsed` but your solution is just better. For some reason I thought it would be faster to do logical indexing for non zero elements, but I was clearly mistaken. Thank you!